# pagination is not working in composite product

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce composite plugin but my pagintaion is not working.
May be its confliction . can we add something to overcome the pagination issue.Please give me correct solutions

Comment: Please report to WooCommerce support. Though, I would advise you to include a lot more detail as right now it is impossible to determine what the problem may be.

Comment: Thanks for reply now i am trying to contact with support team about the pagination issue.